# Recurrence for integer triangles with perimeter $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ be the number of sets $\{x,y,z\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $x,y,z$ are the lengths of the sides of a triangle with perimeter $n$. Obtain a recurrence relation for $a_n$.

I don't understand the solution quoted below that is given. Literally every sentence in it makes a claim that I don't see why. Even the beginning of Option 1 starts with $y+z\ge x+2$ which I don't understand. I could understand $y+z\ge x+1$ for guaranteeing $y+z > x$ and thus preventing degenerate triangles. But why is it $2$ instead of $1$. Can someone give a long explanation of these solutions?

> **Option 1**. If $y+z\ge x+2$, we can subtract $1$ from each to get a triangle on $n-3$. For any triangle on $n-3$, we can add $1$ to each side to get a triangle on $n$ satisfying $y+z\ge x+2$. If $n$ is even, every triangle on $n$ satisfies this, so we get $a_n=a_{n-3}$. If $n$ is odd, there are $\lfloor\lceil n/2\rceil /2\rfloor$ triangles with $y+z=\lceil n/2 \rceil$ and $x=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ that are not counted by $a_{n-3}$. By considering the possible congruence classes, we have $a_{n} = a_{n-3} + \lfloor (n+1)/4 \rfloor$ when $n$ is odd. The initial conditions are $a_n = 0$ for $n \le 0$. This can be written as a single recurrence as $a_{n} = a_{n-3} + 1/2(1-(-1)^n)\lfloor (n+1)/4 \rfloor$.
>
> **Option 2**. Triangles with $y \ne z$ arise by adding $1$ to the two smaller parts of a triangle on $n-2$. There are $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor- \lfloor n/4 \rfloor$ triangles with $y=z$, since there is one such triangle for each $y$ with $n/4 < y \le n/3$. Hence $a_{n} = a_{n-2} + \lfloor n/3 \rfloor - \lfloor n/4 \rfloor$.

Comment: Option 1 starts with **If** $y+z\ge x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about "sets", order doesn't matter, so we can assume $x \ge y \ge z$. 
Let $S_n$ be the allowed sets for perimeter $n$.  Thus $(x,y,z) \in S_n$ if $x,y,z$ are positive integers with $x \ge y \ge z$ and $x < y + z$.

Suppose $n \ge 3$.
We have a one-to-one mapping $(x,y,z) \to (x+1,y+1,z+1)$ from $S_{n-3}$ into $S_{n}$. What members of $S_n$ are not in the range of this mapping, i.e. $(x-1,y-1,z-1) \notin S_{n-3}$?
There are just two possibilities:

1. $z = 1$ (which would mean $z-1 = 0$ is not a positive integer).
2. $y + z = x + 1$ (which would mean $(y-1) + (z-1) = (x-1)$, not $>$.

Actually (1) implies (2), since $y + z = y + 1 \le x + 1$.

Now if $y + z = x + 1$ and $x + y + z = n$, we have $n = 2 x + 1$.
So $n$ must be odd (i.e.  $a_n = a_{n-3}$ if $n$ is even), and $x = (n-1)/2 = \lfloor n/2\rfloor$, $y + z = (n+1)/2 = \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Since we must have $x \ge y \ge z$, $y \ge \lceil n/2 \rceil/2$.
Now check the cases $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$, to see
how many possible values of $y$ there are in each case.  You should get
$\lceil (n+1)/4 \rceil$.